# How can I get an academic post after recently finishing my doctorate research?

Tags: publications, teaching-statement

I have a career question. I recently finished my DBA degree (Doctor of Business Administration) and I am applying for academic posts however, my applications keep being unsuccessful. I am aware that I don't have formal teaching experience, however, I do have informal teaching, tutoring and advising students. In other terms, I was providing freelancing support to students at the Bachelor, Master, and Doctorate levels. I tried to highlight these points in my teaching supporting statement however, I keep receiving negative responses.

My research record was also impacted during the COVID so I am trying now to recuperate for that. Is there any advice that I can use when applying for academic posts?

Also, can you give me any advice on how to get post-doc positions? Shall I keep emailing professors in other universities and show interest in joining their departments?

Comment: What country are you looking in? What types of institutions?

Comment: Do the announcements of vacancies you apply for mention the desired (or required) characteristics of the applicant?  In particular, is DBA an adequate degree?  (As opposed to a PhD. in business.  What degrees did your instructors in business have?)  I would email only departments that have advertised available positions; those ads will tell you where to send your applications.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a duplicate of so many other questions on this forum. Keep searching for posts where people ask what they can do to improve their chances to get a position.

Answer (score 1):

> Shall I keep emailing professors in other universities and show
> interest in joining their departments?

Please, no no no no no. It is called cold-emailing, you as a DBA should know better than me what is the rate of success on this technique.

Find a research theme you are interested into, from there try to see where you can fit into.